# Joomla PHP MySQL Query to use MySQL IF function

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

So i have a Joomla site and in the joomla documentation I can't find anything to do with MySQL's IF, ELSE function within a query.

The part of the query i need a if statement in MySQL is here.

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('container').' != 1');
```

It should be doing something like this :

```
$query->where('IF '.$db->quoteName('server_number').' != '.$number.' THEN '$query->where($db->quoteName('container').' != 1');' END');
```

If the $number input does not match with the server_number column data then to add a where statement to the mysql query.

**Full MySQL Query :**

```
SELECT a.*,ext.media_type
FROM database_hwdms_processes AS a
LEFT JOIN database_hwdms_media AS media ON media.id = a.media_id
LEFT JOIN database_hwdms_ext AS ext ON ext.id = media.ext_id
WHERE (a.status = 1 || a.status = 3) AND a.attempts < 5 AND `container` != 1 AND
 server = 1
ORDER BY a.media_id ASC
```

Want to add a "IF server_number != 1 THEN WHERE container != 1 END" would mean replacing "AND `container` != 1"

Comment: And exactly what does not work when you use the above code with IF and ELSE?

Comment: I added the full MySQL query to my question the output with every single IF method i try just errors. MySQL syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a better way to resolve my problem using MySQL's

> OR ||

function

So my fixed code became this :

**PHP :**

```
$query->where('('.$db->quoteName('server_number').' = '.$number.' || '.$db->quoteName('container').' != 1 )');
```

**In plain MySQL text :**

```
SELECT a.*,ext.media_type
FROM database_hwdms_processes AS a
LEFT JOIN database_hwdms_media AS media ON media.id = a.media_id
LEFT JOIN database_hwdms_ext AS ext ON ext.id = media.ext_id
WHERE (a.status = 1 || a.status = 3) AND a.attempts < 5 AND ( `server_number` = 1 || `container` != 1 )AND
 server = 1
ORDER BY a.media_id ASC
```